# How to access values of state in other function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state, react-props

How can I use the value of state x in handleClick function to show an alert of input value in state x using Function component?

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./App.css";

function About() {
  const [state, setState] = useState({
    x: "",
    output: [],
  });
  //for onChange Event
  const handleChnage = (e) => {
    setState({ ...state, [state.x]: e.target.value });
    console.log(e.target.value);
  };
  //for onClick Event
  const handleClick = () => {
    alert(state.x);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <h1>This is about about </h1>
      <input
        placeholder="Enter a number"
        value={setState.x}
        onChange={handleChnage}
      />
      <button onClick={handleClick}>get Table</button>
    </>
  );
}

export default About;
```

Comment: just use `setState({ ...state, x: e.target.value });` in handleChnage function on first line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two issues should be fixed:

1. You do not need the computed value `[state.x]`, it should be just `x`.

```
setState({ ...state, x: e.target.value });
```

2. The value for the input should be `state.x` not `setState.x`

```
      <input
        placeholder="Enter a number"
        value={state.x}
        onChange={handleChnage}
      />
```

```js
function About() {
  const [state, setState] = React.useState({
    x: "",
    output: []
  });
  //for onChange Event
  const handleChnage = (e) => {
    setState({ ...state, x: e.target.value });
    console.log(e.target.value);
  };
  //for onClick Event
  const handleClick = () => {
    alert(state.x);
  };

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <h1>This is about about </h1>
      <input
        placeholder="Enter a number"
        value={state.x}
        onChange={handleChnage}
      />
      <button onClick={handleClick}>get Table</button>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<About />, document.querySelector('.react'));
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div class='react'></div>
```

Answer (score 4):

It should be `x` instead of `state.x`

```
const handleChnage = (e) => {
  setState({ ...state, x: e.target.value })
}
```

and the value should be `state.x` here instead of `setState.x`:

```
<input
  placeholder="Enter a number"
  value={state.x}
  onChange={handleChnage}
/>
```

Remember on hooks, the first parameter is the value, the second parameter is the setter function.